# Gridview width not fixing

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

I have a grid view and i want it to take the fix width a give it. for the columns that are too long, I want it to break then into rows and merge my fixed width . So far some one suggested putting the grid in div as below.

```
 .container
     {
        width : 1000px;
         height:auto; 
         float:left;
         overflow:hidden;
         display:block;
     }

<div class="container">

  my grid here
</div>
```

i did this and it successfully fix the width by cutting the remaining three columns that fall beyond the width. Please i need something that will force the grid to merge in everything in to given width by breaking long columns in to rows. Any help would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you...

You can fix the column width like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
```

but if your data is too big to fit in there then you have to make short your data to fit in there.